# I'm looking to buy a new car and I'm wondering what does more damage on a car: time or miles?

Tags: fuel-system, maintenance

So the title is pretty self explanatory. I'm looking at getting a minivan, and there is a 2011 model with 50k miles, and a 2008 model with like 30k miles.

What's better? Is it better to have something newer with more miles? The other way around? It depends?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As well as the items suggested by jensgram, it is also important to consider the type of milage it is likely to have, and how well maintained it will be.

A large saloon with a high milage is likely to have been a rep-mobile - it will have done most of its miles on the highway, at high speed. On the other hand, a smaller, older hatchback with very low miles will probably have been owned by an older person, and only used for popping down the shops. IMHO the latter is worse - without being used, seals dry up, parts perish more quickly etc, and maintenance is more likely to have been neglected. On the other hand, a sports car with a low milage is likely to have been a cherished second car, and will have been looked after more carefully.

I normally work on an avarage, for a UK car, of around 10-12k per year, so if a car has done a lot more or less than that I'd be more cautious about it. 50k miles in less than a year seems like an awful lot, and I'd suggest that was probably a commercial/fleet vehicle, wheras 30k in three years sounds quite normal to me. Obviously this does depend on the average milages in your area though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends! A few things to consider:

- One or more owners
- Parked on street or in (heated?) garage
- Insurance may be cheaper for older model
- Newer model may be better equipped

Also, there have been a few questions on idling vs. (highway) miles:

- [Is idling bad for your engine?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/is-idling-bad-for-your-engine)
- [Are there any advantages of idling a vehicle vs. turning it off and back on again?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/888/are-there-any-advantages-of-idling-a-vehicle-vs-turning-it-off-and-back-on-agai)

Answer (score 2):

The real question is: How well was it taken care of? People that don't take care of them do the most damage over time or miles. Does the seller have copies of service records?